# How to recover deleted TAB Sheet from workbook if deleted from back up workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm setting up a repository folder file that will hold my workbook with 10 Sheet TABS. Would you know if one of my tabs is lost or deleted by mistake there is another way for me to recover the deleted TAB from workbook?

This is the back up code that should create, copy tab sheets and set on my folder file back up folder, however, I also tried to include on this code a possible way to add all sheets and I keep getting an error for all other Sheets except for worksheet "TOC"

```
[code:]



Sub CreateWorkBooks()
Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

      If Left(ws.Name, 4) = "TOC" Then


          'Copy one worksheet as a new workbook
          'The new workbook becomes the ActiveWorkbook
          ws.Copy

          'Replace all formulas with values (optional)
          ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value

          'Save the new workbook
          'May want (not required) to add a file name extension (.xls or 
.xlsx) to the file name
          ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & _
                                ws.Range("A1").Value & "Back Up_TOC" & 
ws.Range("Z400") '& ".xls"

          'Close new workbook
          ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

      End If

    Next ws

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

I expected for my code to simultaneously create a copy of all sheets in workbook, then create back up file in folder file, actually code only copies 1 Sheet titled TOC, and I am looking to include a recovery code that will return any deleted TABS from workbook.

Comment: "I keep getting an error" - if you're getting an error is useful to explain exactly what that error is, and on which line it occurs.

Comment: Why not just save a backup copy of the whole workbook as-is ?